# HOW to work clockpicker

Tags: php, jquery, clockpicker

i embed the clockpicker,it can work,but when u change time,it can't be changed

if just have clockpicker code,it's ok but combine with modal code,the time

answer couldn't be change...

i don't know what's wrong with it ,can anyone help me to resolve the question?

thx..

[page link](http://www.ee.nsysu.edu.tw/key/ct.php)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<script src="http://ee.nsysu.edu.tw/key/bootstrap/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ee.nsysu.edu.tw/key/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="http://ee.nsysu.edu.tw/key/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ee.nsysu.edu.tw/key/bootstrap/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://weareoutman.github.io/clockpicker/dist/jquery-clockpicker.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://ee.nsysu.edu.tw/key/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-clockpicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />

</head>

<body>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="@mdo">Open modal for @mdo</button>
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
   <div class="modal-content">
 <div class="modal-header">
 <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">New message</h5>
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
<span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
</button>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<form>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Recipient:</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">Message:</label>
<textarea class="form-control" id="message-text"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="input-group clockpicker" style="width: 50%; float: left;">
<input type="text" class="form-control" value="09:00">
<span class="input-group-addon">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
</span>
</div>
</form>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Send message</button>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>

 <script>
$('.clockpicker').clockpicker();
 </script>
```

Comment: fyi: your `<head>` should be right after your `<html>`. Also, your `<script>` tags at the end of the file should be before your `</body>`.

Comment: <head> is put after <html> originally.and i change the place of <script> that you suggested but it's the same result :(

Comment: "_Originally_"?? You mean in your original code? You should post/paste your original code, how are we gonna find errors if not.

Comment: sorry,my english is not  very well,i post the code,<head> is behind the <html> initially  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> <head>